# How can I query the feature that's closest to the geocode result in Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, viewport, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to create a Mapbox map with thousands of points. I want the user to be able to type an address and a div to be filled with information from the closest point to that address. I'm using the `mapbox-gl-geocoder` control

What would be perfect is if I could use something like:

```
geocoder.on('result', function(e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.result.center)
});
```

But `queryRenderedFeatures` doesn't accept latlong coordinates, it requires viewport coordinates.

The next thing I tried was

```
map.on('moveend', function () {

    var xwindow = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var ywindow = window.innerHeight / 2;
    var xywindow = {'x': xwindow, 'y': ywindow};

    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(xywindow);
});
```

That gives results that are near the queried address, but not the closest point. For instance if I geocode an address where I know a point exists, this query will return a different point a few streets away.

Is there a way to use `queryRenderedFeatures` to get a feature on the location that is returned by the geocode control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But queryRenderedFeatures doesn't accept latlong coordinates, it requires viewport coordinates.

Yes but you can use [map.project](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#project) that *Returns a Point representing pixel coordinates, relative to the map's container, that correspond to the specified geographical location.*

Once you have all the features you'll need to get the distance to each of them to find the closest. [cheap-ruler](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler) would be a good choice for that.

An index like [geokdbush](https://github.com/mourner/geokdbush) probably doesn't make sense here as you're only running it once.