# Get Mapbox point for queryRenderedFeatures based on longitude and latitude

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I found an address with the Mapbox Geocoding API. Then I want to highlight that building on the map.

It works in native, but does not in web. I want to have the point in the mapBox view for the renderedFeatures.

Something like this

```
pointInView = await map.getPointInView(foundAddress.center)
foundBuildings = await map.queryRenderedFeaturesAtPoint(pointInView)
```

How can I convert long,lat to the a point in mapbox-gl-js

*Update*
Found something helpful
[How can I query the feature that's closest to the geocode result in Mapbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537727/how-can-i-query-the-feature-thats-closest-to-the-geocode-result-in-mapbox?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, it's called project(LngLat)

```
pointInView = await map.project(foundAddress.center)
```

See: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#project